# How to find if someone logged into my iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, security, logs

I suspect that someone has logged on my iPhone (physical access, with my code)
Is there a report of all connections with the hours that can be found on the iPhone so I can confirm my suspicions? If yes, do I need a special tool to read it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) I have some questions for you: (1) Do you have access to a Mac? (2) If so, what exact model and what version of macOS do you have? (3) Is your iPhone jailbroken? (4) What version of iOS are you running?